# How can I get html programatically from karma when running phantomjs

Tags: python, angularjs

I'm trying to run ng test from an unattended python script, and need to capture the html in order to forward it developers. The relevant code is:

```
ng test --single-run --progress=false --browsers=PhantomJS
```

PhantomJS appears to emit its output to localhost:9876. Is there any way to redirect this to a file and/or stdout? Or is there a better solution that I haven't imagined yet?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be quite simple. The step that I was missing was that I needed to specify an output directory in the karma.config file. The relevant section of that file now looks like this:

```
htmlReporter: {
  outputDir: 'C:\\TMP',
  templatePath: null,
  focusOnFailures: true,
  namedFiles: false,
  pageTitle: null,
  urlFriendlyName: false,
  reportName: myReport
```